# Replacing RAID Control Battery DELL PowerEdge 2950

Tags: dell-poweredge, raid5, dell-perc

My DELL OpenManage Server Administrator shows 'Battery on Controller PERC 5/i Integrated state as Failed'. 
I purchased the RAID Controller Battery. But, Will it remove my RAID-5 Configuration if I change the battery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration is saved to both controller and each disk. You should be safe doing a power down, change battery and power up.